# Why am I consistently receiving a 403 error in Ocelot API Gateway even after trying to modify Role using JwtTokenHandler in C#?

Tags: roles, http-status-code-403, ocelot

I am actually working on ApiGateway with Ocelot C# but I am always getting 403 error due to the Role. Here is my code :

Ocelot.json:

```
        `"UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/api",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ],
            "DownstreamScheme": "https",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
                {
                    "Host": "myHost",
                    "Port": 443
                }
            ],
            "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/api",

            "RouteClaimsRequirement": {
                "Role": "Admin"
            }`
```

JwtTokenGenerator:

```
`public const string JWT_SECURITY_KEY = "yPdfghjkjhfghjJP";
        private const int JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY_MINS = 20;
        private readonly List<UserAccount> _userAccountList;

        public JwtTokenHandler()
        {
            _userAccountList = new List<UserAccount>
            {
                new UserAccount{ UserName = "admin", Password = "admin123", Role = "Administrator" }
               
            };
        }

        public AuthenticationResponse? GenerateJwtToken(AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authenticationRequest.UserName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authenticationRequest.Password))
                return null;

            /* Validation */
            var userAccount = _userAccountList.Where(x => x.UserName == authenticationRequest.UserName && x.Password == authenticationRequest.Password).FirstOrDefault();
            if (userAccount == null) return null;

            var tokenExpiryTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY_MINS);
            var tokenKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JWT_SECURITY_KEY);

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name, authenticationRequest.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userAccount.Role)

            });            

            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey),
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

            var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = claimsIdentity,
                Expires = tokenExpiryTimeStamp,
                SigningCredentials = signingCredentials
            };

            var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var securityToken = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
            var token = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);

            return new AuthenticationResponse
            {
                UserName = userAccount.UserName,
                ExpiresIn = (int)tokenExpiryTimeStamp.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds,
                JwtToken = token
            };         
        }
        public List<Claim> ValidateJwtToken(string tokenString)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JWT_SECURITY_KEY)),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
         `your text`       ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };

            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            var claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(tokenString, validationParameters, out validatedToken);

            return claimsPrincipal.Claims.ToList();`
```

I already try this : [Ocelot RouteClaimsRequirement does not recognize my claims and returns 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63049670/ocelot-routeclaimsrequirement-does-not-recognize-my-claims-and-returns-403-forbi)
Also by renaming "Role" in everyway possible.
If someone know something it would really help me !!